# SEGV on emitting null root (yaml-cpp)

Tags: yaml-cpp

I am trying yaml-cpp (r589:2c954b1ed301), but I have a trouble with following code.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>

int main()
{
    YAML::Node doc;
    std::cout << doc << std::endl; // SEGV

    doc["sub"] = YAML::Node();
    std::cout << doc << std::endl; // OK

    doc = YAML::Load("");
    std::cout << doc << std::endl; // OK

    std::cout << YAML::Load("") << std::endl; // SEGV
    std::cout << YAML::Load("a") << std::endl; // OK

    YAML::Node doc2 = YAML::Load("");
    std::cout << doc2 << std::endl; // SEGV

    return 0;
}
```

The code is compiled with g++ 4.4.7 on Scientific Linux 6.4.
I am not sure that this error occurs only on my environment. 
I would appreciate your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug, but it was fixed (see the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=212)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and quick response.